# Can I listen to keyboard and mouse events without activating any window?

Tags: java

I want to track number of keys pressed and mouse clicks in background, i.e., without activating any window.

Please, help me to solve my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a keylogger to me..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible using just Java and still keeping it platform independent...

Comment: can you tell me any other way to implement this?

Comment: You can use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to call something that is written in another language like C or C++...if you want to do this for windows take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/27569/). In linux it's even simpler as every device (like the keyboard) is a file there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev